# React / Craco produce a development build that I can deploy to my dev server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, craco

I have a React app which has craco configured. I have the standard scripts for

```
"start": "craco start",
"build": "craco build",
```

I need to be able to create "development" builds that I can deploy. Just like the production build  `yarn build` but I need the non production mode, i.e. development mode like you get when you do `yarn start`. I wish to do this so that I can deploy it to my dev server instance where `yarn start` won't work.

For example I don't want the code minified. And I want the React Developer Chrome Plugin to say it's a development build, not a production build.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks

Mike

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to use `.env` (dotenv) files for different variables related to each environment of yours (e.g. tokens, API keys, etc..). You can read more about it in the [React docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) or in [this](https://dev.to/jam3/managing-env-variables-for-provisional-builds-h37) article.

Comment: I did come across that, I'm not sure that's what I want. What I want for example is for the React Developer Plugin to say that the app is a development build, not a production build.

Comment: And for the code to not be minified, etc. If this all can be done by setting variables in a .env file then fine, but where do I find all the necessary variables to make a production build?

Comment: Regarding the minification, if you want to see the actual code after a build so you just need to enable a source map like it's described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43841807/how-to-enable-source-maps-in-create-react-app

For letting them know it's dev you can add some HTML element (sort of a watermark, style it with CSS) and show it only if a certain flag is on (the flag can be defined in the .env file)

Comment: You either use the dotenv and place them in the server or you use the place where you host your website and use their own system variables configurations for that matter.